# Command for > and < in mathmode

Tags: symbols, mathjax

I am using LaTeX but embedded in XML. I would like to not have to use `>` and `<` directly inside the LaTeX parts.

On the other hand, I would like to not have to write them as HTML entities (`&gt;` and `&lt;`) either. This is such that I can take the LaTeX portions directly and compile them without having to convert the HTML entities into the characters `>` and `<`.

Is there are standard LaTeX command for the symbols `>` and `<` in math mode?

Comment: You can *define* them: `\let\lt<` and `\let\gt>` will allow you to use `\lt` for `<` and `\gt` for `>`. But I don't know whether you're able to make those definitions anywhere in your XML...

Comment: @Werner Defining them in that way is inadvisable in a LaTeX document, since `\let` is a TeX primitive command. It is better practice to use `\newcommand{\lt}{<}`, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about MathJax. It understands some defaults that are not part of default (La)TeX, like `\lt` and `\gt`.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert any specific Unicode character via `\symbol{"####}`, where `U+####` is the character code. Looking [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters), I found that the codes for `<` and `>` are `003C` and `003E`, respectively. I used a `\newcommand` to make referring to these much simpler.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\lt}{\symbol{"3C}}% Less than
\newcommand{\gt}{\symbol{"3E}}% Greater than

\begin{document}

If $a \lt b$ and $b \lt c$, then $c \gt a$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: given your comment under the question saying not to use `\let` as it's a primitive, a bit odd to use `\char`, the latex command would be `\symbol{"3C}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I haven't seen `\symbol{}` before... `\char` was the only command I could find when researching for my answer. I have updated it with that change. Thanks for the tip!