# ! Undefined control sequence. l.11 \forall

Tags: math-mode

I get `! Undefined control sequence. l.11 \forall n,m \gt`

I don't understand why:

```
\documentclass[preview, border=1pt, convert={outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,esint}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\forall n,m \gt n_{\varepsilon} \quad \Longrightarrow  \quad ||\mathbf{x}_n - \mathbf{x}_m|| \lt \varepsilon
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `\ge` and `\le`. `\gt` and `\lt` are not defined.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\forall n,m \ge n_{\varepsilon} \quad \Longrightarrow  \quad ||\mathbf{x}_n - \mathbf{x}_m|| \le \varepsilon
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

#### Edit 1

The > and < signs are already on your keyboard:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\forall n,m > n_{\varepsilon} \quad \Longrightarrow  \quad ||\mathbf{x}_n - \mathbf{x}_m|| < \varepsilon
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you want to use `\gt` or `\lt`, you have to define it. The definition below is taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/298188/156344):

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\lt}{\symbol{"3C}}
\newcommand{\gt}{\symbol{"3E}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\forall n,m \lt n_{\varepsilon} \quad \Longrightarrow  \quad ||\mathbf{x}_n - \mathbf{x}_m|| \gt \varepsilon
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: no I don't want the equal sign

Comment: @GiulianoMalatesta Then why don't you use `>` and `<`?

Comment: that's ok. What's the difference betweem \gt \lt and > < ?

Comment: @GiulianoMalatesta `\gt` and `\lt` are not already defined. I think you are following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/298188/156344) or something similar, but you should make sure that `\newcommand`s are included. IMHO you should just use `>` and `<`. We should not make things more complicated.