# Hat over < symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols, spanish

I want to put a hat over < symbol. I have tried `\widehat{<}` and `\hat{<}`, but neither of them are working. How can I do this?

**P.S.** I am using Overleaf

**Edit** I am using `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`. That seems to be the problem, because if I don't include this package, `\widehat{<}` adn `\hat{<}` work smoothly. How can I solve my problem while using the babel package?

Comment: @Dan `\documentclass{article}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @kubo Does `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}$\hat{<}\widehat{<}$\end{document}` not give you what you are looking for?

Comment: @Dan Yes, it does. However, I am using `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`. That seems to be the problem. How can I solve it?

Comment: @kubo The `babel` package doesn't give me a problem. (Try `\documentclass{article}\usepackage[spanish]{babel}\begin{document}$\hat{<}\widehat{<}$\end{document}`) What other packages are you using? It could be helpful if you added a minimum working example of your code that generates the issue to your question.

Comment: Outside math mode, < occupies the character position of the inverted exclamation mark. Perhaps this is related?

Comment: You might try adding a command to access the < character implicitly. See this relevant solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298172/command-for-and-in-mathmode. 

Placing `\newcommand{\lt}{\symbol{"3C}}` in the preamble and using either `$\widehat{\lt}$` or `$\hat{\lt}$` works for me, even with `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`. Of course, this may get cumbersome if you have to do something similar for several other symbols, but it is a start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this should be reported as a bug in `babel-spanish`.

Anyway, since typing `\widehat{<}` is not really good because it will produce wrong spaces, you can use a workaround: define a command *before* the special action of `babel-spanish` enters the scene.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\newcommand{\lesshat}{\mathrel{\widehat{<}}}

\begin{document}

$a<b\lesshat c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to type `\hat{<}` or `\widehat{<}` in the body of the document, you can't unless you load

```
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
```

but, as I said at the beginning, this would produce wrong spacing because `\hat{<}` would be considered an ordinary symbol.

Thanks to [Dan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117125/dan) for pointing out that in a former version of the answer `\string` was not needed.

Comment: In English, "hatless" means "without a hat", so this command name rather contradicts itself, although unintentionally.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Right. I'll reverse. I guess that `\lesshat` will raise less eyebrows.

Comment: Good choice.  (By the way, the pedant in me says that should be "fewer eyebrows".  But it's not otherwise confusing.)

Comment: Well if you want to raise eyebrows, one could read `\lesshat` as Les shat. He might have done so on Pen Island.

Comment: @Dan Yes, that's right, because only `<` is made active, not `>`, by `babel-spanish`.

Comment: @egreg Sorry, I mis-typed `>` instead of `<` in my comment, but for me both (<,>) still work fine without `es-noquoting`.

Comment: @egreg `\documentclass{article}\usepackage[spanish]{babel}\begin{document}$\hat{<}\widehat{<}$\end{document}` for instance compiles just fine.

Comment: @Dan Doh! Yes, now I know why.

Answer (score 3):

I add my solution with the option `\selectlanguage{spanish}` that not give no error of compilation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\selectlanguage{spanish}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widehat}{\mathord}{largesymbols}{98}

\begin{document}

\[f(x)<g(x)\mathrel{\widehat{<}}h(x)\]

\end{document}
```

[image]